# Why is an assignment of a list at [1:1] only possible with an iterable?

Tags: python-3.x

```
a = [1,2]
a[1:1] = 3
```

raises the Exception:
TypeError: can only assign an iterable

If I change the variable to an iterable, no exception is raised.

```
a = ['a','c']
 a[1:1] = 'b'
```

Why does the assignment of the slice [1:1] raise an exception, if the variable is not an iterable?

Comment: because it tries to match each position

Comment: What do you mean by each position? Isn't from 1 to 1 just one position?

Comment: yes, but for it is a slice of size `n`, even if `n  == 1`, that is why `a[1:1] = [3]` would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because is expecting to match positions, since for him `a[1:1]` is a slice of size `n` even if `n == 1` it will expect an iterable of size at least 1. For example that is why this works:

```
>>> a[1:1] = [3]
>>> a
[1, 3, 2]
```

Comment: if a = [1,2], why is it that print(a[1:1]) is showing the empty list []? Is it not of size 1 as well?

Comment: @David, imagine that you need to iterate from 1 till 1 , if you are there it means that you finished the iteration right? so it never happends!